# i18n multilanguage functionality not responding while using the dropdown.Works only with this command "ng serve --configuration=esp --port=4200"

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, multilingual

Need a help to implement the multilanguage functionality in this project so that after deployment onto the testing server the language can be changed when hitting the dropdown. Now in development server if the language needs to be changed it can be done with help of the command mentioned above.Any help would be great.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="right-blog" >
  <select class="language-btn d-flex align-items-center" [value]="langCode" (change)="setLang($event)">
  <option value="en-US">English</option>
  <option value="esp">Spanish</option>
  <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
export class HeaderNavComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      langCode="";
      ngOnInit() {
      this.langCode='en-US'
      if(localStorage.getItem("langCode")){
      this.langCode=atob(localStorage.getItem("langCode"))
       }
     else{
     localStorage.setItem("langCode",btoa("en-US"))
       }
      }
     setLang(event:any){
    localStorage.setItem("langCode",btoa(event.target.value));
    window.location.href="/" + atob(localStorage.getItem("langCode"))+this.router.url
  }
}
```

**Angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "shopping-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "i18n":{
      "sourceLocale":"en-US",
      "locales": {
        "esp":"src/i18n/messages.esp.xlf",
        "hi":"src/i18n/messages.hi.xlf"
      }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/shopping-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "esp":{
              "baseHref": "/esp",
               "localize":["esp"]
            },
            "hi":{
              "baseHref": "/hi",
              "localize":["hi"]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "shopping-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "shopping-app:build:development"
            },
            "esp": {
              "browserTarget": "shopping-app:build:esp"
            },
            "hi": {
              "browserTarget": "shopping-app:build:hi"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "shopping-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ngx-translate: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core I have used it in a lot of projects and it works just fine

Comment: Hi, while it's a good suggestion, it is not really an answer to the question.